# Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'CronOptions'

Tags: javascript, angular, cron

I want to use cron-editor in my angular form but getting this error in the terminal,

[image]

These are the `cronOptions` I was using.

```
 this.cronExpression = '4 3 2 12 1/1 ? *';
    this.cronOptions = {
      formInputClass: 'form-control cron-editor-input event',
      formSelectClass: 'form-control cron-editor-select',
      formRadioClass: 'cron-editor-radio',
      formCheckboxClass: 'cron-editor-checkbox',

      defaultTime: '10:00:00',
      use24HourTime: true,

      hideMinutesTab: true,
      hideHourlyTab: false,
      hideDailyTab: false,
      hideWeeklyTab: false,
      hideMonthlyTab: false,
      hideYearlyTab: false,
      hideAdvancedTab: true,

      hideSeconds: false,
      removeSeconds: false,
      removeYears: false
```

The error I am getting in my terminal is:

> Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type
> 'CronOptions': formInputClass, formSelectClass, formRadioClass,
> formCheckboxClass, and 12 more.

**Edit:** I have declared as `public cronOptions: CronOptions;` where the type is imported as `import { CronOptions } from 'cron-editor/lib/CronOptions';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the two way binding.

Options passed to a component are usually just inputs, not outputs.

There error states that : it does not recognize the CronOptions as an Event.

```html
<cron-editor [cron]="cronExpression" [options]="cronOptions">
</cron-editor>
```